# Substitute NA values depending of position in dataframe

Tags: r, row, interpolation, na, missing-data

I would like to substitute the NA values by a previous and posterior rows average values. Moreover, when the first or last lines are NA values I would like just the repeat next and before rows, accordingly. My real data have negative and decimals values.

My input:

```
1.0   NA    1.0
NA    2.0   2.0
3.0   3.0   NA
```

My expected output:

```
1.0   2.0   1.0
2.0   2.0   2.0
3.0   3.0   2.0
```

Cheers!

Comment: to clarify, the `NA` in column 1 is replaced by the mean of the two values immediately above and below (`1.0` and `3.0`) or the mean of the two complete rows above and below (`mean(c(1.0, NA, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, NA)`)?

Comment: Yes, is the mean between two values immediately above and below, not the entire collumn! It is your question? Thank you for help.

Comment: *'substitute value with average of previous and next'* is called ***interpolation***. And *'repeat last non-NA'* is called filling, with carry-forward/backward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use the `na.approx` function from the `zoo` package. Note that this has a slightly different behavior (than the solution by @flodel) when you have two consecutive `NA` values. For the first and last row you could then use `na.locf`.

```
y <- na.approx(x)
y[nrow(y), ] <- na.locf(y[(nrow(y)-1):nrow(y), ])[2, ] 
y[1, ] <- na.locf(y[1:2,], fromLast=TRUE)[1, ]
```

EDIT: @Grothendieck pointed out that this was much too complicated. You can combine the entire code above into one line:

```
na.approx(x, rule=2)
```

Comment: Anyway, this takes information in same collumn of NA to replace it, right? Always based in above and below values...
What´s is the difference to consecutive values?

Comment: or just: `na.approx(x, rule = 2)` or `na.approx(x, rule = 2, method = "constant")` depending on what you want.

Comment: Suppose in one column, you have 1, 2, NA, NA, 5. Then `na.approx` will give you 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. @flodel's answer will give you 1, 2, 2, 5, 5. Both seem like reasonable answers, just to slightly different questions.

Answer (score 3):

All vectorized after turning your data into a matrix (which will also make computation faster):

```
x <- matrix(c(2, NA, 3, NA, 2, 3, 1, 2, NA), 3, 3)

p <- rbind(tail(x, -1), NA) # a matrix of previous value
n <- rbind(NA, head(x, -1)) # a matrix of next value
m <- matrix(rowMeans(cbind(as.vector(p),
                           as.vector(n)), na.rm = TRUE), nrow(x)) # replacements

ifelse(is.na(x), m, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple to solve:

```
library(imputeTS)
na.interpolation(x)
```

That's it already.